# Name resolution does not work in chrooted ArchLinux ARM

Tags: arch-linux, chroot, arch-arm

#### What I did

Install qemu, qemu-arch-extra, qemu-user-static (AUR) in ArchLinux X86_64.
systemd takes care of the binfmt, verified from `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/`.
Download ArchLinux ARM tarball from its website. The direct link is this
`http://os.archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-aarch64-latest.tar.gz`.
Extract it in a folder with `sudo bsdtar -xpf` command. Copy the
`/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static` file into that folder. Chroot with `arch-chroot`.

In commandline:

```sh
sudo pacman -S qemu qemu-arch-extra
sudo yay -S qemu-user-static
sudo bsdtar -xpf ArchLinuxARM-aarch64-latest.tar.gz -C folder
ls /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static folder/usr/bin
sudo arch-chroot folder
```

#### Result

In the chrooted environment, I can ping any IP address but can not ping any
remote host (e.g. `example.com`) i.e. name resolution does not work.
`/etc/resolv.conf` file is populated. `ip` shows correct configs of NICs.
So, how can I enable name resolution in chrooted ArchLinux ARM? I have tried
the same procedure in Ubuntu X86_64 with chrooted into Ubuntu AARCH64. It works.

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: The content is `nameserver 1.1.1.1`, same for x86_64 and aarch64, not symlinked, actual file 0644.

Comment: What if you add other known servers? for example: `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` (Google DNS server)

Comment: Same error. As I said that name server work in host OS ArchLinux X86_64.

Comment: What is the output of `ping example.com`? What is the output of `getent ahosts example.com`? What is the output of `dig example.com`?

Comment: @ctx `ping` shows `Temporary failure in name resolution`, `getent` no output, ArchLinux ARM has no dig.

Comment: Have you started systemd-resolved ?

Comment: @solsTiCe yes, it's on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly, you don't need to copy `qemu-aarch64-static` into `folder`
- Secondly, it seems your `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/` is empty. It needs to be populated with the needed binary.

  To fix that, you can use the `binfmt-qemu-static` package from AUR that will take care of that for you.

  And finally, you need either to *reboot*, or restart *systemd-binfmt*

With this setup, this works very fine for me, and I don't have to do anything to get name resolution in the chroot.

Instead of *arch-chroot*, one can use also:

```
systemd-nspawn --bind-ro=/etc/resolv.conf -D folder -M myFancyMachineName
```

The trick here is not to use `--resolv-conf` switch (neither of them worked for me) but use a specific bind option.

Comment: Copying `qemu-aarch64-static` into `folder` **was previously** required.  The feature which allowed it not to be was introduced in Kernel 4.8 and I've had trouble getting it to work with Ubuntu 18.04 / Kernel 4.15.  The OP hasn't listed versions so I would be cautious about suggesting it's not required.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Ok. I have never done that before. I didn't know about it.

Comment: I've tried with systemd-nspawn but same error. Name resolution works in armv7, armv5 chrooted env. Also binfmt_misc are already registered from qemu-arm-static package. Maybe there is an issue in my system. I'll check it out.